# mvn clean install or any other command to create a maven project is not working [Build Failure]

Tags: maven, plugins, build, maven-plugin

I'm trying to create project in maven but when I execute either "mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false"  or "mvn clean install", it's not able to download the plugins or jars from the repository.
See the error in picture.[Error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0y30.png)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: Network problems?